# Php Curl not working After Upgrade to x64. Its enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, curl, 64-bit, wamp, upgrade

I have just updated my Server to

```
PHP 5.6.4 x64
Apache 2.4.10 x64
```

I have uncommented

```
extension = php_curl.dll
```

Extension directory path is correct too and php_curl.dll file even exist in ext directory. when i run code it says

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in D:\waserver\www\test.php on line 3
```

I have replaced php_curl.dll with diff. versions of x64 from http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ but it still not resolve the issue. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Q: *"How to resolve this issue?"* A: Downgrade to your previous working configuration. --- But: Enable error **logging**. Take a look into the error log it should tell you what happens when the extension can not be loaded (probably SSL libraries or other dependencies). If nothing is given there, you edited the wrong php.ini perhaps as the extension was not tried to load.

Comment: Additionally your question has been asked and answered before, I've closed against the duplicate until you can provide more information that shows all the options from the duplicate Q&A are extensively tried through and it didn't work for you. Just edit your question if you can provide the information so that it is more clear what makes your question different from the existing one. Additionally contact WAMP for your support options, e.g.: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=curl%2064bit%20site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fforum.wampserver.com%2F

Comment: thanks for guidance... here is error ... AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::c18:f9ff:2d66:7b8. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:/Program Files/waserver/php564/ext/php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Dec 26 19:19:17.427583 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3956:tid 480] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: did u find solution to ur problem

Comment: i have tested in many of version of php, fix come only for 5.4.3 yet... all later version are buggy and we can't do anything else than wait or downgrade to 5.4.3 with patch of curl